# ALSA not working RPI 3 - speaker-test failure

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, raspberry-pi3, alsa

I recently installed Jasper on my Raspberry Pi 3, but upon running it encounter a slew of ALSA errors. Thus, I tried simply running speaker-test, but received the same errors.

```
speaker-test 1.0.28

Playback device is default
Stream parameters are 48000Hz, S16_LE, 1 channels
Using 16 octaves of pink noise
ALSA lib confmisc.c:768:(parse_card) cannot find card '1'
ALSA lib conf.c:4259:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:4259:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1251:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:4259:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:4738:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
Playback open error: -2,No such file or directory
```

My user is in the audio group and I am fully sudo apt-get upgraded. Not sure why my sound isn't working.

Comment: Can please run this command aplay -l and share the output

Answer (score 0):

This fixed:

Try adding **dtparam=audio=on** to **/boot/config.txt**

Source: [Alsa doesn’t work on my Raspberry Pi 2/3](https://discourse.osmc.tv/t/alsa-doesnt-work-after-last-update/10600/2)